# How Modify route standard Rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I am using Rails3 and I would like make one request for get one parameter token to my controller different of ID to my action "confirms "in my controller,can someone help me?
I believe  is a problem in my route.

such as:

http://0.0.0.0:3000/emails/1QWD3DF2Cd/confirms or http://0.0.0.0:3000/emails/confirms/1QWD3DF2Cd

```
`
class EmailsController < ApplicationController  
      def confirms
        @email = Email.find(params[:token])
        @email.confirmed # other method in model emails which mark as enable  
     end
end
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this

Add this to your routing.rb file.

```
match '/emails/confirms/:token' => 'emails#confirms', :as => 'confirms_emails'
```

Comment: Also it's possibile to do the same, but more obviously by using match in resource matcher.